# Controlling the Size and Position of a Child Window with Another Parent

Tags: c, winapi

I am designing a window pane manager control, similar to a splitter bar control, only more complex/advanced.

A parent window, possibly the main window, would create an instance of the pane manager control, and then create several children windows and register those children with the pane manager control.

When the child windows are registered with the control, `SetWindowPos()` is called on each child with the `HWND_TOP` z-order change with styes  `SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER` set. The children then display properly.

The issue I am having is with the z-order of the control and the children windows. When the main window is resized and my control determines that certain children should be moved rather than resized, those moved children have issues. The children that are moved seems to change z-order under the control, then back over every other time the child is moved. Could it be that when the main window is resized the children's parent's call `DefWindowProc()` and that sends move/resize commands on top of the move/resize commands I am sending? If so, how do I prevent that if I don't have control of the parent window?

```
LRESULT PaneMgrWinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case CPMM_REGISTERPANE:
        {
            LPPANESTRUCT pane = (LPPANESTRUCT)lParam;
            g_hWndZone1Pane = pane->hWnd;
            SetWindowPos(m_hWndZone1Pane , HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER);
        return 0L;
        }

        case WM_MOVE:
        {
            RECT rc = {0};
            GetPaneRect(ZONE1, &rc);
            MapWindowPoints(hWnd, GetParent(g_hWndZone1Pane), &rc, 2);
            SetWindowPos(g_hWndZone1Pane, 0, rc.left, rc.top, 0, 0, (SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE));
            return 0L;
        }

        case WM_SIZE:
        {
            RECT rc = {0};
            GetPaneRect(ZONE1, &rc);
            MapWindowPoints(hWnd, GetParent(g_hWndZone1Pane), &rc, 2);
            SetWindowPos(g_hWndZone1Pane, 0, rc.left, rc.top, (rc.right - rc.left), (rc.bottom - rc.top), SWP_NOZORDER);
            return 0L;
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` for the parent and `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` for all children?

Comment: A parent windows doesn't send any messages to the child window if it is resized. Also the Z-Order isn't changed on a move, as long as the window has the WS_CHILD style. For popup windows the behavior is different.

Comment: @Daniel Sęk Confirming that all children have WS_CLIPCHILDREN and WS_CLIPSIBLINGS window styles. All window class styles, including the control, have CS_HREDRAW and CS_VREDRAW set.

Comment: @xMRi If not a z-order change from the parent when moving, then what else could it be? It is possible that the children do not have z order issues and instead have visibility or drawing issues. The outcome is that only the control background is shown in those panes when the child is not shown. In fact, I can confirm WM_PAINT is not sent when they are moved when the children don't show..

Comment: Did you rechecked this with Spy++ if there is realy a change. Also you can track the windows messages.